Bash script - While loop is getting stuck only when running from azure pipeline
I wrote a bash script to perform a deployment restart in Kubernetes. When the script is run manually within the VM everything goes fine and is completed in a couple of minutes.
However when I run the same script using an azure pipeline (where the agent is the same VM I previously used to run the script) the the script is getting stuck when reaches below loop.
I've changed the code a couple of times (as below) but is still getting stuck, even after the condition have been met.
echo "Waiting for the secret to be created ...... "
secretloop=`kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l`
while [ $secretloop -eq 0 ]
do
    echo "inside dev secret loop ...... " >> /tmp/var.txt
    secretloop=`kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l`
    sleep 1
done

----------

echo "Waiting for the secret to be created ...... "
secretloop="$(kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l)"
while [ $secretloop -eq 0 ]
do
    echo "inside dev secret loop ...... " >> /tmp/var.txt
    secretloop="$(kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l)"
    sleep 1
done

----------

echo "Waiting for the dev secret to be created ...... "
while [ $(kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
do
    echo "inside dev secret loop ...... " >> /tmp/var.txt
    sleep 1
done


By getting stuck  do you mean that kubectl command never returns or that -eq 0 condition is always true and loop runs multiple times?

I found the issue. The working option is the third one (including the kubectl command directly into the condition). The only additional thing I was missing is that I needed to add "sudo" before the command. I didn't have to do it within the VM because the user it was part of the suddoers.
PS. The first two were still getting stuck within the loop even though I added the sudo to the command.
echo "Waiting for the dev secret to be created ...... "
while [ $(sudo kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
do
    echo "inside dev secret loop ...... " >> /tmp/var.txt
    sleep 1
done



I didn't have to do it within the VM because the user it was part of the suddoers.

I suspect this would have been easier to debug with a simpler design, but most importantly, always test as close as possible to exactly the conditions of actual use. That includes logging in as the user the automation would use, and using the same method to switch ids, etc.
Aside from that, some observations -
You tagged this as bash. I generally recommend using double-bracket tests in favor of single-brackets ([[ ... ]] instead of [ ... ]), though for what you are doing, you should really simplify thoem away entirely.
Rather than
secretloop=`kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l`
while [ $secretloop -eq 0 ]

or even
while [[ $(kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]

just take out the unnecessary layers and steps, and maybe switch to an until to avoid negative-test issues.
until kubectl get secrets -n dev | grep "dev"; do

If either kubectl or grep returns a nonzero exit code the condition is false.
This will loop until kubectl outputs (to stdout) that it sees a Secrets object in the dev namespace with the string dev somewhere on the line for grep to catch, which means probably in the name of the Secrets object.
You could refine that by using one of these -
kubectl get secrets -n dev -o name # will have object type, e.g. "secrets/" on the front
kubectl get secrets -n dev -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name # bare name, no type

If you know the name exactly you can drop the grep. For example, if the name of the Secrets object is actually "dev", then -
$ kubectl get secrets -n dev --no-headers=true -o name dev         
secret/dev
$ kubectl get secrets -n dev --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name dev
dev

so you could say
until kubectl get secrets -n dev dev # creates decent logging...
do date +'%c waiting on dev...'; sleep 1; done

but if "dev" is just a string that's a part of the name, that won't work.
You'd still need the grep, as in this (quieter) version:
until kubectl get secrets -n dev --no-headers=true -o name | grep -q dev
do date +'%c waiting on dev...'; sleep 1; done


Although all of this might be great advice, it's not an answer to the question.

ita vero; mea culpa. Slightly edited - still only nominally relevant, but better. Thanks for the callout. There should be an https://idownvotedbecau.se/ for that. :)
